# How to set the Params with id having key and value and pass id dynamically in calling the API

Tags: angular, typescript, api, angular8, rest

I have set the params with id having key and values which needs to be pass dynamically as received from the server (ex:s1,s3,s4..these are sensor names received from the server) and I have to pass these sensor names dynamically .

**.service.ts**

```
export class DashboardService {
  public sensors: any[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
  }

  sensorstart(tokenstr) {
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + tokenstr
      }),
      params: new HttpParams().set('id', JSON.stringify(this.sensors.map(itm => itm.name)))
    };

    this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/api/sensors/start?' + this.id, httpOptions).subscribe(
      (senst: any[]) => {
        // localStorage.setItem("senst",JSON.stringify(senst));
        console.log('senst:', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('senst')));
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);

      },
      err => {
        console.log('Error', err);
      }
    );

  }
}
```

**.component.ts**

```
 this.jammerstart();
--some code--

sensorstart(){
  this.senst=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("senst"));
console.log("senst",this.senst)
}
```

But in console It is showing

```
{
    "status": true,
    "action": "sensor started"
}
```

But I want to show the sensor name in action what I have called dynamically in calling the API.

```
{
    "status": true,
    "action": "sensor s3 started"
}
```

note:s3 is whatever we have set the id i.e sensor name(it will be change according to the API)

How can I Pass the id values (sensor names s1,s2,s3--)dynamically in calling the API.

Comment: What is the senst response you are getting from server

Comment: The response from the server is   {
    "status": true,
    "action": "sensor s3 started"
}    it is the object and the values s1,s2,s4,s5 --- are the sensor names and I have to pass these sensor names as id  dynamically according to this it is showing the response as object as mentioned above object.can you help me how to call this id's dynamically .

Answer (score 0):

You should use Object.keys

I assumed you got a response from API like an Array of object

```
[
  {
    's1': 'some value 1',
    's2': 'some value 2',
    's3': 'some value 3'
  }
]
```

then you should use this.

```
[{'s1': 'some value 1','s2': 'some value 2','s3': 'some value 3'}].forEach(element=> { console.log(Object.keys(element))});
```

and if you got Object then use this.

```
{
  's1': 'some value 1',
  's2': 'some value 2',
  's3': 'some value 3'
}

Object.keys({'s1': 'some value 1','s2': 'some value 2','s3': 'some value 3'}).forEach(ele=> {console.log(ele);})
```